# Aptana - Different PHP projects same deploy directory

Tags: php, deployment, aptana

I have a PHP project in Aptana which files I want to share with others projects. I can do this by properties project -> resources -> linked resources. But I want to deploy on the server this project in all the projects that share this.

For example: Project 1) CMS library (/cms), Project 1 Web Site (w/eb1), Project 2 another web site (/web2).

On the server I need: web/cms and web2/cms without need to copy manually cms folder into web1 and web2.
It's that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you using linux then just make links to your needed folders.
If you using windows try making shortcuts to that folder. I think that should work.

EDIT:

This will help you: [Windows XP vs Vista: NTFS Junction points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432487/windows-xp-vs-vista-ntfs-junction-points)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer so fast. I've tried but it dosen't work, although I can see in IIS the folder (the shortcut) I get the same error : Warning: require(./cms/DPEngine.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\shop\index.php on line 7 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './cms/DPEngine.php'

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792905/is-it-possible-to-create-a-windows-shortcut-using-php

Comment: Thanks again, but I work localy in windows and with unix in production so I can call window functions. I was thinking if there is a way of copy folders automaticaly in Aptana IDE like you can do with an ant script in the Java world ... The links idea sounds good if works in windows and unix without extra code.

Comment: In linux it works. Dont know about windows. I use windows only as game station :D

Comment: Oh, I think you can use SVN for this too. Only think what you have to do is to set dirs where project lies and update them with inbuild client. I dont actualy remember does aptana has SVN, but truly have GIT.